# Playing audio on Raspberry pi with java

Tags: java, audio, raspberry-pi

Hi i have this code here

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;

public class Playmusic implements Runnable {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Thread t = new Thread(new Playmusic());
        t.start();
    }   

    @Override
    public void run() {
        AudioInputStream audioIn;
        try {
            audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("test.wav"));
            Clip clip;
            clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(audioIn);
            clip.start();
            Thread.sleep(clip.getMicrosecondLength()/1000);
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException | LineUnavailableException | InterruptedException  e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

to play a sound on the raspberry. But when i run it, it doesn't produce any output.
I've tested it on both Windows and Linux systems where it works.
The program does notice the file though since it sleeps for the whole duration of the sound and doesn't give me any Runtime exception. 
It also can't be the speaker that's causing the problem because i can play the sound with 
`aplay test.wav` and it gives me an output. I wanted to use the JavaFX library but it seems to be removed on the cut down java version of resbian.

Comment: Did you try running this on say Windows? You're making it specific about raspberry-pi, but that would be a red herring if the code doesn't work somewhere else either.

Comment: Yes i have tried it on Windows and Linux and it works on both. I think java has some kind of problem noticing the audio output

Comment: You should edit your question and add the fact that the code is tested and working on Windows and Linux; its a rather important clue that it indeed may be raspberry-pi specific. When you run java -version on the PI, what does that output?

Comment: java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)

Comment: This may be unrelated because the OP is using mp3 and JLayer, but it seems like it could help: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1337/how-can-i-get-java-sound-to-work

Comment: Just a thought. Are you sure that clip is streaming to the proper audio output? There are usually quite a few, inclusive of "virtual" audio streams; if it's running, but not producing sound, I would wager that it's streaming it to the wrong source.

Comment: How can i change to where it is streaming within java? I have thought of that too but havn't seen a solution yet. I have an external soundcard and the normal audio with aplay and mgp321 are streamed to it automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Java or Raspbian... Check the RPi configuration `sudo raspi-config`, and ensure you are having your audio output well configured between HDMI or Jack Out. That should do the trick...

Comment: This is correct but what if we have selected an external USB sound card as default audio device? In my case, it works to record audio (as it is the only recording device detected by the system) but while aplay reproduces audio with it (I have configured it in asound.conf) Java sticks to internal jack audio, which is much worse quality as any cheap USB audio card. Any clues on how to make JDK use the selected audio output device?

Comment: Did your card work fine on Raspbian?, for example, by recording and playing directly with the tools of the system?

Comment: Yes, it works with any Alsa commands. Anyway, I have solved it forgetting about uSB microphone and using a simple old USB sound card with audio input output. Works great and the recording quality is much better Than USB micro, while also shows no problem with 16000 rate.